# How can I add a bound DataGridView to a User Control using the visual studio designer?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a DataSet as a Data Source in my project, which comes from a database. There are two tables (companies and contracts), and they're linked by a foreign key. The DataSet designer correctly identifies the key and sets up the related tables.

I'm able to drag a contracts DataGridView onto my form, and then drag the related companies DataGridView. When I run the app, these are automatically linked - the designer creates the binding source and correctly sets the two grids up.

My question is, I'd like to be able to move the companies (child) DataGridView to a separate UserControl. When I try to drag a grid over in the same way to a User Control, however, the binding doesn't work. How can I do this?

(On a related note, is setting up the bindings using the designer the best way to go?)